# Is it possible for a vhost to only listen to the generic ip?

Tags: apache-2.2, ip

Is it possible for a VirtualHost to listen to the public IP, without having to set it in the file (but by using the environment configuration) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName $IP;
    # If my server public ip is 123.123.123.123, Apache will automatically replace $IP with this ip.
</VirtualHost>
```

I ask this because I will setup multiple servers and it would be faster to do something like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you know that there are tools like ansible, chef or puppet? They have templates, it will allow you to make it clean.

Answer (score 0):

By using `<VirtualHost *:80>` the virtual host is already available on all ip-addresses, so that probably won't do. That `*` should be replaced with the specific ip-address you want to bind the virtual host to, if you're going the route of [IP-based Virtual Hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/ip-based.html).

The [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername) should be a fully qualified domain name and not an ip-address.

The [first VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html) entry becomes the default virtualhost and will be used for requests not matching any of the subsequent ServerName or ServerAlias directives, such as requests to the ip-address.

You can use [environment variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html#syntax) in your apache configuration, no problem. The syntax to use environment variables is `${VARIABLE-NAME}`.

```
<VirtualHost ${IP}:80>
    ServerName ${HOSTNAME}
</VirtualHost>
```